# SAS and Curl: 'env' in url causes error

Tags: sas

I'm trying to use CURL with SAS 9.3.  I got it working for normal webpages.  However, when I try to use it with a URL with 'env', I get the following error message: 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  Is there some CURL function that I can use in a filename statement, so CURL will recognize 'env' as part of the URL?  Also, I tried proc http, but couldn't get it to work with a proxy.  This is why I started using CURL.  Thanks very much for any suggestions.

SAS code:

```
%let url=%NRSTR(https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.option_contract%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'YHOO'&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys);

filename curl pipe "curl -K &url 2>&1";

data _null_;
  infile curl lrecl=32767;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

Comment: What are you executing this on - Windows or UNIX?

Comment: I'm executing this on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I've hit this issue before and it took a while to figure out.

It turns out that you need to use a caret `^` to mask any ampsersand `&` characters whenever you process it through the command line pipe.  Looking back at it now I have no idea how I figured it out...

Also - you need to use a lowercase `-k` I believe.

I cleaned it up a little and this worked fine for me:

```
%let query= %sysfunc(urlencode(SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.option_contract WHERE symbol='YHOO'));
%let env  = %sysfunc(urlencode(store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys));
%let url  = https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=&query^%nrstr(&)diagnostics=true^%nrstr(&)env=&env;

filename curl pipe "d:\sasdev\common\bin\curl\curl.exe -k &url 2>&1";

data _null_;
  infile curl lrecl=32767;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

Note that you'll want to change the path to curl.

Comment: Robert,  Thanks so much for sharing how the yql url should be constructed in SAS.  This probably saved me hours of work.  Thanks again!

Comment: Followup question: How do I get curl to output an XML file in this example?  Do I need to use a curl command to specify the output file type?  Note I tried -H "Content-Type: text/xml" but it did't work. Thanks very much.

Comment: Curl is just going to repeat whatever content the webserver returns to it.  What you need is to find a way to tell the webserver to return XML.  Depending on the site's API it may be possible to do this kind of thing by adding a parameter such as '&type=xml' or something similar.  I'd advise reading the site's documentation, or if possible, interactively visit the site within your web browser to see if there is an option, run it, and see how the URL changes.  Also don't forget to mark the above answer as accepted if it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: I read the site's documentation and according to them the default is XML.  However, when I try to use an XML map that I created with XML Mapper 9.3, I get the following error message: "ERROR: Expected an XML document prolog or element."  I looked at infile in the log and noticed there are a bunch of numbers and dashes which precede the XML data. I believe they are causing the error.  Normally, I would create a string variable and parse them out, but I want use this code download large volumes of data which means the ~32K length restriction in SAS will become an issue.

Comment: Referencing the above comment, does anyone have an idea on to remove junk data from an infile without using a string variable?  Or perhaps doing it with a string variable but circumventing the ~32K restriction?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Start of XML data is at the '<':    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1092    0
1092    0     0   1591      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1591<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Welcome to the joy of dealing with the web&xml in SAS =)  Yeah the 32k limitation is insane.  I suggest asking a new question as the comments are going to get pretty ugly if I try and walk you through it here...

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding quotes that will get passed to Windows.

Something like

```
"curl -k ""&url."" 2>&1"
```

The doubled double quotes are passesd as a single " character to Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  filename statement now executes.  However, now I'm getting a different error.  Log says: error trying to read config from https//query.yahooapis.com.... file curl: no URL specified!

Comment: Note that I think the filename statement now executes because of the lowercase `-k` compared to the uppercase `-K` you listed in your question.