# SAS web scraping

Tags: web-scraping, sas

I would like to get latest HIBOR rate from the website of [HKAB][1].

Here is the following code i tried: While it give error in filename statement

```
data parm;
    format yyyymmdd $8.;

    yyyymmdd = put(date(), yymmddn8.);

    yyyy = put(substr(yyyymmdd, 1, 4), $4.);
    mm = put(substr(yyyymmdd, 5, 2), $2.);
    dd = put(substr(yyyymmdd, 7, 2), $2.);
    *url = 'http://www.hkab.org.hk/hibor/listRates.do?lang=en&Submit=Search&year='||yyyy||'&month='||mm||'&day='||dd;;
    format url $1024.;
    url = 'http://www.hkab.org.hk/hibor/listRates.do?lang=en&Submit=Search&year=' || yyyy || '&month=' || mm || '&day=' || dd;
    url2 = 'curl ' || url;
    call symput('url',url);
    call symput('url',url);
    call symput('url',url);
    call symput('url',url);
    call symput('url2',url2);

    put _all_;
run;

%put &url2.;
filename hiborpage url &url.;


  [1]: http://www.hkab.org.hk/hibor/listRates.do?lang=en&Submit=Search&year=2015&month=1&day=26
```

Comment: A valid url needs quotes? Why the multiple call symput('url')?

Comment: Take a look at this question, I think you'll find what you're looking for there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584928/sas-and-curl-env-in-url-causes-error

Answer (score 2):

Your `fileref` exceeds 8 characters. Change `hiborpage` to something shorter, like `hibor`. Also, as Reeza mentioned, put `&url` in double quotes. Macro variables won't resolve in single quotes. That should fix the errors.

There are also ampersands in the url. Ordinarily, you'd just put a string like this in single quotes, but because it's in a macro variable, you need the double quotes. The problem is that SAS tries to resolve what it thinks are macro variables in the url and gives you warnings when it fails. To avoid these warnings, use the macro function `%nrstr()` to mask the ampersands in your macro variable, e.g.:

```
%let url3 = %nrstr(&url);
filename hibor url "&url3.";
```